# Custom template pipe fuctions in Tornado

Tags: python, tornado

How do you define a custom template pipe function that is available on all template in Tornado.

Trying to achieve something like this:

```
{{ name | transform_me }}
```

Comment: I don't think tornado's default library supports filters that way. I mean you can define functions that you can apply but your syntax will be `{{ transform_me(name) }}`. What templating library are you using? `jinja2`?

Comment: yeah, i just do like that i have to pass the function to every template as context. I want to define it globally so it's available on all templates by default. Do you know if this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass custom `ui_methods` with Application, that will be available in all templates:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web


class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("mytemplate.html")


def my_custom_function(handler, *args):
    # handler is the RequestHandler of current handled request  
    # args are the agrs passed through template
    return 'my_custom {}'.format(str(args)) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = tornado.web.Application(
        [(r"/", MyHandler),],
        # expose function to the templates
        ui_methods={'my_custom_function': my_custom_function}
    )
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

and template file

```
{{ my_custom_function('adsadasda', 'qweqweq') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have your *controllers* share a Base RequestHandler whose 
`get_template_namespace` method is overwritten.

You probably want to have a filters module.

**filters.py**

```
def transform_me(value):
    # transform value
    return transformed_value


filters = {
   'transform_me': transform_me
}
```

**Shared base class**

You can add your filters to the template namespace. When `render` is called from handlers that inherit from `BaseRequestHandler`, your filters will be available.

```
from filters import filters

class BaseRequestHandler(RequestHandler):
   def get_template_namespace(self):
       namespace = super(BaseRequestHandler, self).get_template_namespace()
       namespace.update(filters)
       return namespace
```

### Reference:

- https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/web.py#L887